# Обход ассоциативного массива по порядку

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```
var array = {
  mail1@mail.ru: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
  mail2@mail.ru: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}],
  mail3@mail.ru: [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
};
```

Обхожу каждый элемент массива for(item in array), но обработка происходит не по порядку, а нужно именно в том порядке который в массиве. Гугл советует использовать for, но не могу найти как. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не вполне понятно, что имеется в виду под порядком.
Перебрать поля объекта, предварительно их отсротировав, можно с помощью 
    [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) и [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
var array = {
  'mail1@mail.ru': [],
  'mail3@mail.ru': [],
  'mail2@mail.ru': [],
  'mail4@mail.ru': [],
};

Object.keys(array)
  .sort(/* Здесь можно наводить любой порядок, какой душе угодно*/)
  .forEach(key => console.log(key, array[key]));
```

PS не стоит называть объекты массивами

Comment: Неверно описал код, на самом деле там массив, и sort() помог. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

У Вас `array` это не массив, а объект. А в объекте нет понятия `порядка полей`. Перебрать все поля и их значения можно циклом `for in`. Но в каком порядке они будут перебраны стандарт не говорит ничего. Единственное условие, что будут перебраны `все` поля

```js
var array = {
  "mail1@mail.ru": 1,
  "mail2@mail.ru": 2,
  "mail3@mail.ru": 3
};

for (item in array)
  console.log(item + ': ' + array[item]);
```

Comment: Спасибо, я с этим разобрался, но все таки есть ли способ обойти по порядку?

Comment: Определить для начала, что именно вы считаете порядком. Например, это  сортировка по алфавиту.

Потом получить список полей объекта Array, сохранить их в массив Array2, отсортировать по алфавиту.

А потом, проходя по Array2, получать имя поля (`Array[i]`) и производить нужные действия над `array[Array2[i]]`.

Comment: `Но в каком порядке они будут перебраны стандарт не говорит ничего.` - ES7 уже говорит. :)